# SendGrid Inbound Parse japanese (encoding: shift_jis) text garbled

Tags: character-encoding, sendgrid, shift-jis

Currently we are using SendGrid Inbound Parse to receive emails.
We handle the Inbound Parse webhook request by Azure HttpTrigger function implmented in C# (.NET 6).
When the received email is in UTF-8 encoding, everything's okay.
However, when we tried to receive email in shift_jis encoding, headers are okay,
but japanese characters in text and html are garbled.

From Inbound Parse request, we got the charsets as below:

- subject: UTF-8
- to: UTF-8
- from: UTF-8
- cc: UTF-8
- html: shift_jis
- text: shift_jis

And the string we got directly from request.form["text"] (or "html") was already garbled like "�e�L�X�gshiftJis-007"
(should be "テキストshiftJis-007"), so we cannot use string in request directly.

Then we tried to convert (System.Text.Encoding.Convert method) it from charset encoding (shift_jis) to utf-8,
and the result was different from original string but still unreadable "?e?L?X?gshiftJis-007".

Our questions are:
When using C# HttpTrigger Azure function to handle Inbound Parse webhook request
(request data is passed through AspNetCore.)

1. What encoding is in html/text string in Inbound Parse webhook request
   when the email is send in encoding other than UTF-8?
2. How to read text and html in shift_jis encoding (or other encodings excluding UTF-8)
   correctlyfrom an Inbound Parse webhook request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. I would recommend reaching out to the [support team](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) because it requires to investigate the payload to figure out what is going on.

I also tried to replicate the issue on my end with using [send_raw](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/settings-inbound-parse/create-a-parse-setting) option. Here's the payload, and it does contain shift_jis characters. You may be able to process the payload manually.

(stripped X-Mailer info)

```
'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="shift_jis"\n' +
    'X-Mailer: \n' +
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n' +
    '\n' +
    '\n' +
    '=83e=83L=83X=83gshiftJis-007\n'
```

Comment: Support team send me here, so your answer will be the savior.
Thank you for your recommendation, and we decided to switch to send raw option and parse it by ourselves.